# How to add a column in resource class from pivot table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can add a column to response?

I have coded my resource class as below;

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $response = parent::toArray($request);
    $journeys = Journey::whereIn('id',$this->journeys->pluck('journey_id')->toArray())->get();
    $response['journeys'] = JourneyResource::collection($journeys);

    return $response;
}
```

My pivot table;

---

packet_id * journey_id * is_new_journey(boolean)

---

I want that the column is_new_journey can be added in each journey.

An example for json response with a column added:

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "customer_id": 1,
        "name": "packet name",
        "code": "code13",
        "parent_id": null,
        "created_user_id": 1,
        "journeys": [
            {
                "id": 742,
                "name": "Live Event and Remote Class Test",
                "desc": "Live Event and Remote Class Test",
                "activation_date": "2020-06-30 17:08:21",
                "is_active": 1,
                "customer_id": 1,
                "users_count": 0,
                **"is_new_journey": 1**
            }
        ]
    },
```

My Packet Model:

```
class JourneyPacket extends Model
{
   public function created_user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'created_user_id');
   }

   public function journeys(){
    return $this->hasMany(JourneyPacketJourney::class, 'packet_id');
   }
```

Comment: could you please attach `Journey` model?

Comment: @V-K There is nothing you could benefit in the Journey Model.

Comment: I need to see the relation, which contains pivot

Comment: @V-K I didnt make any relation with this table in Journey class. But you can understand from my pivot table as you see in above. They have many to many relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do it,

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        $response = parent::toArray($request);
        $journeys = Journey::whereIn('id',$this->journeys->pluck('journey_id')->toArray())->get();
        foreach ($journeys as $journey){
            $journey["is_new_journey"] = $this->journeys->where('journey_id',$journey->id)->first()->is_new_journey;
            //dd($journey);
        }
        $response['journeys'] = JourneyResource::collection($journeys);

        return $response;
    }
```

And then, you can add this column into JourneyResource class;

```
'is_new_journey' => $this->is_new_journey
```